# Limit destribution of $n(Y_{N}-1)$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, $Y_{n}=\max\{X_{1},X_{2},\ldots,X_{n}\}$ and $X_{1},X_{2},\ldots \in \text{Pa}(1,2)$

Tags: probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

This is a question from the book *An intermediate course in Probability* by **Allan Gut**:
Suppose that $X_{1}, X_{2},\ldots $ are independent, $\text{Pa}(1,2)$-distributed random variables, and set $Y_{n}=\max\{X_{1},X_{2},\ldots,X_{n}\}$. Show that $n(Y_{n}-1)$ converges in distribution as $n\rightarrow \infty$, and determine the limit distribution.

This is what I tried:

$F_{Y_{n}}=(F_{X}(x))^{n}=P(Y_{n}<y)=(P(X<y))^{n}=(1-(\frac{1}{y})^{2})^{n}$

$Z=n(Y_{n}-1)\qquad P(Z<z)=P(n(Y_{n}-1)<z)=P(Y_{n}<\frac{z}{n}+1)=(1-(\frac{1}{(\frac{z}{n}+1)})^{2})^{n}$

$(1-(\frac{1}{(\frac{z}{n}+1)})^{2})^{n}\rightarrow ? \quad\text{as}\quad n\rightarrow \infty.$

According to the book, the limit distribution should be $\text{Exp}(\frac{1}{2}),\,f_{U}(u)=2e^{-2x}$, but I couldn't see that it does. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I assume you mixed up the parameters of the pareto distribution. If  $$X \sim \text{Pa}(1,2)$$ then $$P(X < y) = 1 - \frac{2}{y} \not= 1 - \left(\frac{1}{y}\right)^2$$ In general we have  $$X \sim \text{Pa}(k,j)$$ then $$P(X < y) = 1 - \left(\frac{j}{y}\right)^k \not= 1 - \left(\frac{k}{y}\right)^j$$